# Getting Julia to talk to Mac Plotting Devices

Tags: macos, julia

Running julia code from the command line, cannot get plots to show.

Simple example:

```
using ImageView
using Images

img = load("../images/cat.jpg")
imshow(img)
```

In a notebook 
`img` shows the image, but running the above script from the command line, the code runs without fail, but no plot is ever visible.

Have searched, but have not been able to find documentation on how to get it to talk to, e.g., Quartz (like R does) or other plotting device.

Any help or redirecting to resources would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: There seems to be [an issue on MacOS](https://github.com/JuliaImages/ImageView.jl/issues/175) with `ImageView.jl` likely to be related to `Gtk.jl`. Does it look like your problem?

Comment: Quite likely.  Thanks!  I submitted a follow-up.